# How to slowly change the letter spacing of an h1 once the div it's in is clicked?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, boolean, overflow, letter-spacing

I have a class I named '.social' that I have open up once the div is clicked. Inside is a switch case statement so that once it is clicked, if you click it again, the div closes back up. I am only showing one letter within it, using the 'overflow' and letter spacing attributes to hide the rest of the letters. Once the div is clicked, I want to expand the div, and decrease the letter spacing together, so that all of the word is displayed.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var SocialClick = true;

$('.social').mousedown(function () {
    switch (SocialClick) {
        case true:
            $('.social h1').css({'letter-spacing': 'none'}, 1000);
            $(this).stop().animate({ width: '150px' }, 500);
            SocialClick = false;
            break;
        case false:
            $(this).stop().animate({ width: '50px' }, 500);
            SocialClick = true;
            break;
        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.social {
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 50;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -52px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #fff;
}

.social h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #000;
    letter-spacing: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to move the `letter-spacing` style to the `.social` div and animate it there, using the same `animate` function call as for the `width`.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CU4cR/2/)

```
.social {
    letter-spacing: 50px;
    ...
}
...
$(this).stop().animate({ width: '150px', letterSpacing: '0px' }, 500);
...
$(this).stop().animate({ width: '50px', letterSpacing: '50px' }, 500);
```

Comment: Works perfectly now, thanks for the Fiddle. Can't +1 you because I'm not a 15, but if I could I would!

Comment: @Karmaxdw why don't you accept an answer? People will stop answer your questions. Have you noticed here on SO the green checkmark near the "correct" answers?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the letter-spacing to a valid value:

```
$('.social h1').css({'letter-spacing': 'normal'}, 1000);
```

Is there anything else you were having a problem with?  That's is the only question I could glean from your post.

EDIT:

```
$('.social h1').animate({'letter-spacing': 'normal'}, 1000);
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified what my questions were. That fixed the problem with changing the letter-spacing, but I am not sure how to set the duration.

I switched to $('.social h1).animate, but with no avail.

Comment: Simply use the animate like you did for the width but instead use letter-spacing as the attribute. I made an edit to my post.  Does that help?

Comment: It doesn't work for me. The box expands and the word slides over, but it won't change the letter spacing

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to animate the letter-spacing this works with jQuery 1.8.1+

```
$('.social h1').animate({'letter-spacing': '0px'}, 5000)
```